# Sequelize create make more than one record issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to save logs on some events with sequelize create but when I call the create method more than one record saved (maybe 2 or 3 identical records).
I'm using node.js and sequelize.
I made sure that I called add method once and I **await** it.
controller:

```
async addLog(){   
    
     let log = await UserLog.addLog({Uid:user_id,date:new Date()})
    return log
  }
```

UserLog model:

```
public static async addLog(logObject: LogType) {
        return await LogEntity.create(logObject, {raw: true});
      }
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure addLog() function is getting called from one point only.

You can use [upsert](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-upsert) function of sequileze which inserts a new record only if a unique condition doesn't meet else it will updates the record. In your case Uid and date can be used for uniqueness.

Comment: upsert and unique key are very good ways to workaround but I want to know the real reason behind this issue.
and yes I made sure that I called addLog() from one point.
thank you